# Cannot uninstall Anaconda on mac

Tags: python, anaconda

I first tried the method at this link https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install/uninstall/
and tried to rm -rf the folder, but the folder is still currently in my opt file.

Then I tried to use `conda install anaconda-clean` by the time I try to use `anaconda-clean --yes` it just gave me a command not found error.

Now I can clearly see that the anaconda3 folder is still in the opt folder, and for this reason, I cannot reinstall this because it will show that "anaconda has already been installed" and asks me to update instead of reinstalling it.
The issue now is that I can neither install nor uninstall anaconda. I do now know how to progress next.

Comment: On ubuntu using the terminal and deleting the folder in opt works, and often you can achieve a similar outcome on Mac. It's worth a shot.

Answer (score 1):

I went through the exact same scenario that you described when I went to remove the old version of Anaconda to replace it with the Apple Silicon compatible version (2022.05 most recently)

I tried (did not work):

- installing `anaconda clean` package
- running the commands `conda clean --yes` and `conda clean -a`
- running in Terminal `rm -rf anaconda3` as well as iterations of that like `rm -rf ~/anaconda3`, `rm -rf ~/miniconda3`, etc.

None of this worked. When I searched "Anaconda" in Finder I could clearly see that it was still in the opt folder, and as you said, this prevented me from downloading the new version.

Finally, I just **opened \opt in Finder** and **deleted the anaconda3 folder** there and viola! it was all gone.

Comment: my /opt/anaconda3 folder doesn't show up in my Finder anymore. When i use `locate anaconda3` it shows many files that are in /opt/anaconda3/, but i cant remove it.

Answer (score 0):

open your terminal and enter and then remove directory or enter rm -rf ~/anaconda3 (this command works if you have anaconda 3)

Comment: This is actually what I did, for unknown reasons it is not removing the anaconda3 file despite me using rm -rf